# Change foreground property of CalendarGlyph in CalendarDatePicker

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I need to change, in UWP, the color of Segoe MDL2 Assets font inside of CalendarDatePicker, to make it looks like this (blue icon):

[image]

I've looked in the Dinamic Tree of my app, and I believe I need to change "Foreground" property of CalendarGlyph in CalendarDatePicker:

[image] [image]

I know how apply styles to CalendarDatePicker, but I don't know how apply styles to specific elements inside of CalendarDatePicker.

Comment: Use blend, right click the element, there should be something like style-> edit copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `CalendarDatePickerCalendarGlyphForeground` SolidColorBrush resource:

```
<CalendarDatePicker>
    <CalendarDatePicker.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CalendarDatePickerCalendarGlyphForeground" Color="CornflowerBlue"/>
    </CalendarDatePicker.Resources>
</CalendarDatePicker>
```

To apply this to all calendar date pickers, scope the resource appropriately (e.g. put it in the `Application.Resources` resource dictionary in App.xaml.cs for it to apply app-wide).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for!